# How about Akka-grpc with flatbuffers, thoughts?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, grpc, flatbuffers, akka-grpc

I have started working with Akka-GRPC using ProtoBuffers, the samples online are very clean and concise, but with Flatbuffers being faster than ProtoBuffers and GRPC stating out of box support for FlatBuffers, can we use flatbuffers with Akka-Grpc, I have started working on it and FlatBuffers seems much more work than what ProtoBuffer offers, so my question is, is it worth using FlatBuffers, is it possible to use FlatBuffers with AkkaGrpc(Since, its JVM at the end, still unsure though) and are there any child projects to do the same.

I understand we have Filo but any other alternatives
https://github.com/velvia/filo

Answer (score 0):

Likely no. First, GRPC for FlatBuffers currently works for C++, Go, and is being worked on for other languages, but does not exist for Java (or Scala) as far as I know.

Even if it did exist, I'm not familiar with Akka, but if it integrates directly with Protobuf (which it looks like it does) then supporting FlatBuffers would require more work by the Akka developers. I'd ask with them.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick and concise response. Its all the information I needed, I'll proceed with ProtoBuffers for now and will wait for support on Java or Scala maybe in the soon future.